# Socket io domain setup

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Could not figured out this seemly so simple question.

So I have built a project with socket io and it worked perfectly locally.

On server side I do

```
 var server = express();
 var serv = require('http').Server(server);
 var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
 serv.listen(8000);
```

And client side is

```
var socket = io();
```

So when I try to access the project locally I just go to command line to turn on the server and access http://localhost:8000/.

Now I have uploaded the whole project to my domain and the path is http://foo.com/project

I cannot access the server by either visiting http://foo.com:8000 or http://foo.com/project:8000.

I can access the index.html though but then there is no server-client communication.

I tried to change the client side to `var socket = io.connect("http://foo.com/project:8000")` still not working

Comment: Does your hosting provider support webSocket connections?  What exact errors do you get?  When you look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger what does it show when the client tries to make the webSocket connection?  This is the type of debugging you need to learn how to do to gather clues about what's happening here.

Comment: If I visit http://foo.com/project:8000 I will be re-directed to a wp-admin/setup-config.php page and console will say "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1". If I visit http://foo.com:8000 I will get the CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error... not too sure the webSocket connection support though...

Comment: It doesn't sound like your node.js server is properly listening on port 8000.